# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection for API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, es6-promise

I am trying to console.log some data for a weather API, but when I go look up a location I get the error message

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)`

My code so far is this on my server

```
app.post('/weather', (req, res) => {
    const url = `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${DARKSKY_API_KEY}/${req.body.latitude},${req.body.longitude}?units=auto`
    axios({
      url: url,
      responseType: 'json'
    }).then(data => res.json(data.data.currently)).catch(error => { throw error})
  })

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server has started")
})
```

and my Javascript

```
  fetch('/weather', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      latitude: latitude,
      longitude: longitude
    })
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    setWeatherData(data, place.formatted_address)
  }).catch(error => { throw error})
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
axios(...).then(...).catch(error => { throw error;})
```

will lead to that warning if your `axios()` call or the `.then()` handler has a rejection.

When you throw the error in your `.catch()` handler that leaves the promise chain in a rejected state and you have no further code to catch that rejection.

The exact same issue is true of your client-side code.

---

You should also understand that `.catch(error => { throw error;})` does absolutely nothing useful.  It catches the rejection, then throws which just rejects the chain again.  And, since there is nothing else listening to the promise chain, it's an unhandled rejection.

What you need to do instead is to actually handle the error in some way that is appropriate for your application such as send an error status back to the client.

```
axios(...).then(...).catch(error => {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

And, in the client, you can either show the user an error message or just log the error.  rethrowing the error if there's nobody listening to catch it does you no good.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with the promise. But I am now getting a request failed with a status 403

Comment: @faizan_khan98 - Well a 403 is specific to your endpoint.   The [std definition for a 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) has something to do with authorization for that specific resource in the vein of the client is authorized generally, but not allowed to access that specific resource.  Now, not all servers implement their 4xx codes in the proper way so you will have to figure out with your endpoint why you are getting a 403.  I would first verify that everything in the URL is exactly right, then verify that any authorization or API key you have is proper.

Answer (score 2):

```
axios({
      url: url,
      responseType: 'json'
    }).then(data => res.json(data.data.currently)).catch(error => { console.error(error)})
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing when I started. :)

You wouldn't *throw* a baseball from the *catch*er's mitt, so you shouldn't throw an error from a `catch` method either. You can however throw from the `then` method and it will be caught by the following `catch` method.

Anyway, you should handle the error in the catch method. In most cases the error will be sent to that catch method automatically if it's a real error. If it's an error hidden inside a successful API request, you'd have to manually throw the error like I mentioned above.

```js
.catch(error => yourCustomErrorHandlerThatShouldBeAvailableGloballyAndDefinitelyNotHaveANameThisLong(error))
```

Your custom error handler can do whatever you want. You can forward it to a service you're using to track crashes, you can display something to page visitors, you can print it to the console, make the page spin around really fast and explode, create an animated cat rainstorm, redirect to Darth Vader yelling "NOOOOOOO!". Sky's the limit.

Comment: This is wrong that you would never throw from a `.catch()`.  There are many cases where it makes sense to throw from a `.catch()`.  In fact, .catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err}); is exactly how you would log an error and then let it continue to propagate back to the caller.  But, you would only  do this when some other code is listening for the resulting rejected promise (which the OP's code does not have).

Comment: I don't see what that post has to do with anything.  Yes, you can use `throw err` from a `.then()` handler to change the promise into a rejected chain, but you can also use it just fine from a `.catch()` for the same purpose.  Your first sentence in your answer is just wrong.  You can throw from a `.catch()` and there are reasons to do so when you have some other code watching the chain and catching that error later down the chain.

Comment: That post is relevant because it offers an example of throwing inside of a catch, while also explaining why it can be bad to throw from a catch (black hole). I offered it as an example for you and OP. Now, I personally would rather clearly, simply, and concisely handle the error in the catch method and not have the error get tossed through a chain of catch methods. If you're into that, that is your choice. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Throwing from a `setTimeout()` is a black hole.  That's completely different.  It's the same as throwing from any plain asynchronous callback.  This is one reason why promises are better than plain callbacks (easier to propagate errors).  Lots of respected code finds reasons to catch a rejected promise, do something and then rethrow. Here's a simple example.  You open a file, you start writing to it (using promises). You get an error in a `.catch()`. You close the file, perhaps even remove it, then throw the error from the `.catch()` so the promise stays rejected and the caller gets the error.